# List<string> not sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

The string is returned the same as it enters the function:

```
  public static string AlphaSort(string S)
      {
        var NewS = new List<string>();
        var Arr = S.Replace(" ", "").Split();
        NewS = Arr.ToList();
        var SortedS = NewS.OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
        return String.Join("", SortedS.ToArray());
      }
```

I have also tried `NewS.Sort()` to no avail

Comment: what is your delimiter when you are splitting the string?

Comment: What do you want to split on? String.Split() with no arguments will just pass in a char[0]

Comment: it sorted in VS, the Online IDE I was using was the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overthinking things. Try something like:

```
public static string AlphaSort( string s )
{
  string sorted = string.Join( "" ,
                    ( s ?? "")
                    .Split()
                    .OrderBy( x => x )
                    ) ;
  return sorted ;
}
```

which turns this string

```
"The    Quick Brown Fox      Jumped Over      The Lazy      Dog"
```

into this string

```
"BrownDogFoxJumpedLazyOverQuickTheThe"
```

If you're trying to order the individual characters, it gets *much* easier. A `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>` (very convenient). It's also readily convertable to a `char[]` (since that's ultimately its backing store). In this case, something like

```
public static string AlphaSort( string s )
{
  string sorted = new string(
                    (s ?? "")
                    .Where( c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) )
                    .OrderBy( c => c )
                    );
  return sorted ;
}
```

Given the input noted above,

```
"The    Quick Brown Fox      Jumped Over      The Lazy      Dog"
```

this produces the string

```
"BDFJLOQTTacdeeeeghhikmnoooprruuvwxyz"
```

One might note that once you're looking at characters, the ordering is no longer really alphabetic. Rather, it's an ordinal sort, since a `char` is an unsigned short.

Here's another approach

```
public static string AlphaSort( string s )
{
  char[] chars = s.ToCharArray() ;

  Array.Sort( chars ) ;

  int i = 0 ;
  while ( i < chars.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i]) ) ++i ;

  string sorted = new string( chars , i , chars.Length-i ) ;
  return sorted ;
}
```

producing the same

```
"BDFJLOQTTacdeeeeghhikmnoooprruuvwxyz"
```

from

```
"The    Quick Brown Fox      Jumped Over      The Lazy      Dog"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to take a string and return the characters alphabetically. If so, try this

```
public static string AlphaSort(string S)
{
    var Arr = S.Replace(" ", "").ToCharArray();
    var SortedS = Arr.OrderBy(c => c);
    return String.Join("", SortedS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string AlphaSort(string S)
  {        
    var Arr = S.Replace(" ", "").Split(' ');
    var NewS = Arr.ToList();
    var SortedS = NewS.OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
    return String.Join("", SortedS.ToArray());
  }
```

or simply you could use without using Replace:

```
var Arr = S.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the string sorted case insensitive

```
public static string AlphaSort(string S)
{
    string[] NewS = S.Split(' ');
    Array.Sort(NewS, new CaseInsensitiveComparer());
    return String.Join(" ", NewS);
}
```